# JavaFX create a small live preview of pane

Tags: java, javafx, preview

I have a project where I have two windows, basically you could compare it with powerpoint in presentation mode. In one of my windows I would like do show a small preview in a corner of what is shown on the entire second window. If there would be a copy method for nodes I think i could manage to realize it but I couldn't find any.

For better understanding I tried to visualize my problem.

[image: how my setup should look]

Comment: Try to layout a thumbnail  size simple pane over a bigger one, as you want it. Post here your attempt (see [mcve] ) when you run into difficulties.

Comment: snapshotting a node is always a possibility, but if you do this too often, you'll most likely get memory issues. An alternative would be creating the same node types for both windows and do some binding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could always take continuous snapshots of the other `Stage`'s `Scene` (or some arbitrary `Node`) and display them in your "live image" area. Here's an example:

**Main.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Main Window");
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();
    ((MainController) loader.getController()).displayOtherWindow();
  }

}
```

**MainController.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainController {

  @FXML
  private ImageView imageView;
  private AnimationTimer imageTimer;

  public void displayOtherWindow() throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Other.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load(), 500, 300);

    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Other Window");
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.show();

    ((OtherController) loader.getController()).startAnimation();

    imageTimer = new ScreenshotsAnimationTimer(scene);
    imageTimer.start();
  }

  private class ScreenshotsAnimationTimer extends AnimationTimer {

    private final Scene scene;

    private ScreenshotsAnimationTimer(Scene scene) {
      this.scene = scene;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(long now) {
      imageView.setImage(scene.snapshot(null));
    }

  }
}
```

**Main.fxml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="MainController" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="500.0">

    <center>
        <VBox spacing="10" alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
            <padding>
                <Insets topRightBottomLeft="15"/>
            </padding>
            <Label text="Some controls. These buttons do nothing."/>
            <Button text="Button #1"/>
            <Button text="Button #2"/>
            <Button text="Button #3"/>
        </VBox>
    </center>

    <bottom>
        <VBox>
            <Separator/>
            <HBox minHeight="105" maxHeight="105">
                <padding>
                    <Insets topRightBottomLeft="5"/>
                </padding>
                <Label text="Some other information could go here. Live image is to the right."
                       maxWidth="Infinity" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" wrapText="true"/>
                <Separator orientation="VERTICAL"/>
                <ImageView fx:id="imageView" fitWidth="166.66" fitHeight="100"/>
            </HBox>
        </VBox>
    </bottom>

</BorderPane>
```

**OtherControler.java**

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.SequentialTransition;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class OtherController {

  @FXML
  private Rectangle rect;

  public void startAnimation() {
    SequentialTransition transition = new SequentialTransition(
        createTransition(500 - rect.getWidth(), 0),
        createTransition(500 - rect.getWidth(), 300 - rect.getHeight()),
        createTransition(0, 300 - rect.getHeight()),
        createTransition(0, 0)
    );
    transition.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    transition.play();
  }

  private TranslateTransition createTransition(double x, double y) {
    TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(1), rect);
    tt.setToX(x);
    tt.setToY(y);
    return tt;
  }

}
```

**Other.fxml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.Group?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>

<Group xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
       fx:controller="OtherController">

    <Rectangle fx:id="rect" width="200" height="100"/>

</Group>
```

**Image of result**

[image]

---

I did notice some stuttering when trying to move either `Window` around. A more complicated application may also cause some lag. In other words, you should tune things for your application's performance. For instance, do you really need a screenshot *every* frame? Maybe you could take a screenshot every other frame or maybe every `n` frames. Another possible optimization is to use the same `WritableImage` for the snapshot (only creating a new image if the `Scene`'s dimensions change).

Also note that in my example I use a lot of hard coded values. You'll want to change that for a real application.